# Pythonic v. Unpythonic

Tags: python

In a code review challenge, I recently had the below code called unpythonic:

```
def word_count(string):
wc_dict = {}
word = ""
index = 0
while index < len(string):

    if string[index].isalnum():
        word = word + string[index]
        index += 1  
    else:
        if word:
            if word.lower() in wc_dict:
                wc_dict[word.lower()] += 1
            else:
                wc_dict[word.lower()] = 1
        word = ""
        index += 1

if word:
    if word.lower() in wc_dict:
        wc_dict[word.lower()] += 1
    else:
        wc_dict[word.lower()] = 1

return wc_dict
```

I also submitted different code for a challenge I wrote in Ruby, and had that solution called "Pythonic".

What does code mean to be Pythonic/Unpythonic?

Comment: Unpythonic = Pythetic :-)

Comment: You can iterate directly over strings, you know.  That's probably one thing that juts out at me.

Comment: [Googling "pythonic"](https://www.google.com/search?q=pythonic) gives some pretty clear results explaining the term.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that "pythonic" means **"conforming to usual idioms for python in order to write easy to read code"**.  Your example is not pythonic as it could (probably) be written much more easily.

e.g. using regular expressions + `collections.Counter` turns this into a pretty obvious 2-liner:

```
words = re.findall(r'\w+', string)
wc_dict = collections.Counter(words)
```

If you only expect to be splitting on whitespace, that makes it even easier:

```
wc_dict = collections.Counter(string.split())
```

95% of the time, if you're working with single characters from a string, there's a better way.

Answer (score 1):

I very much agree with @mgilson's definition of (un-)Pythonic above, but will expand on this case a little more.

I would say that one of the reasons this code was probably described as "un-Pythonic" is because it appears to be a fairly literal translation of C code to do the same thing. I've also seen many cases of Python code that appeared to be based on familiarity with Java or C#, and their respective data structures, standard libraries, and stylistic conventions.

Other than `dict`, the OP's code doesn't appear to use any of Python's advanced data structures or iteration capabilities.

Even where `dict` is used, it's in kind of a less-than-fluent way. This code:

```
if word.lower() in wc_dict:
    wc_dict[word.lower()] += 1
else:
    wc_dict[word.lower()] = 1
```

... could be replaced trivially with a more succinct version (this could also be shortened into a one-liner with `defaultdict`):

```
wc_dict.setdefault(word.lower(), 0)
wc_dict[word.lower()] += 1
```

None of this is meant as a criticism of the OP as a thoughtful programmer, by the way: this is a seemingly reasonable and correct algorithm to solve the problem. It just doesn't take advantage of many Python features which experienced users will be familiar with.

Comment: No worries on the criticism; I am still very much a newb and am just realizing that there are usually many more ways than 1 (or 2,3) to solve a problem.

Comment: Yeah, I want to emphasize that from what I can see this is simply a lack of familiarity rather than a lack of clear thinking :). [The Zen of Python](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) says that "There should be one--and preferably only one--obvious way to do it." That opens up a lot of debates and judgment calls for complex problems, but one of the benefits I've found is that most experienced Python programmers tend to think about this issue and resist solving problems in obscure or unreadable ways.